# TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, program-entry-point, typeerror

I'm trying to create a `main()` in a class file in Python 2.7.11 and run it, but Python is claiming I need to pass `main()` an argument.

```
def main(self):
    howManyBadCrops = BadCropsDetector() # My class
    # a bunch of stuff goes here that runs the module....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why is this happening? Here is my terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "badCropsDetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    class BadCropsDetector:
  File "badCropsDetector.py", line 66, in BadCropDetector
    main()
TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: There is no compiler, this is not java :)

Comment: Sorry. Will remove the terminology, very used to working in Java xD.

Comment: I just wanted you to realize that you were programming Java in Python (you talk about "compilers", you defined the `main` function inside a class and wanted to call it without referencing the class). Stop thinking in Java and programming in Python will be easier for you

Comment: Indeed that was my issue. Hard to switch gears from `main` inside Java classes to `main` outside of Python classes as a beginner Python programmer. Thank you for the distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, you don't need the `self` argument in the function definition of `main`.  This is because `main` is plainly a module level function, you only need to specify the `self` when you are writing a function contained inside a class (i.e. a *method*).

Simply remove it from the definition:

```
def main():
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Removed the `self` argument and simply put `def main()` outside the class and the problem was fixed.

Comment: I love this clear and concise answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: In my opinion it is not the best practise to remove self from function definitions in python